# Django: Fetching parent data using childs Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble fetching my parent data using child.

models.py

```
class Company_Data(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    company_address =  models.CharField(max_length=254)
    company_tel_no =  models.CharField(max_length=254)
    company_fax_no = models.CharField(max_length=254)


class Requirements(models.Model):
    req_service         = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    req_coverdate_from  = models.DateField()
    req_coverdate_to    = models.DateField()
    req_duedates        = models.DateField()
    company             = models.ForeignKey(Company_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def business_setup(request):

    req = Requirements.objects.filter(req_service = 'Business Setup')

    context = {
        'req' : req ,
    }
    return render(request, 'admin_template/content/admin_businesssetup_req.html', context)
```

Template HTML

```
{% for requirements in req %}
<table>
                    <tbody>

                      <tr>
                      <th style="width:50%">Company Name</th>
                      <td>{{ requirements.company_id.company_name }}</td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                      <th> Covered Date From </th>
                      <td>{{ requirements.req_coverdate_from }}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th> Covered Date To </th>
                      <td>{{ requirements.req_coverdate_to }}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th> Due Date </th>
                      <td>{{ requirements.req_duedates }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

{% endfor %}
```

what im trying was `requirements.company_id.company_name` to display the related company name but no luck. what i have found was querying the Parent *`Company_Date`* to display the Child *`Requirements`*. but i want to filter the `Requirements` table and display it's parent, so those won't be applicable for me.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You just have to write "company" instead of "company_id" in your template

<td>{{ requirements.company.company_name }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks this was the right answer for me. Note to self, try using the name of the models not in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Just use that

```
<td>{{ requirements.company__name }}</td>
```

For more you can visit django documentation page in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)